# Wrap XML response with JAXB and Jersey

Tags: xml, parsing, jaxb, jersey

I use Jersey to implement my REST API and I have the following service:

```java
@Path("discoverytopology")
public class DiscoveryTopology {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public List<Definition> getDefinitionList() {
        List<Definition> definitions = db.getDefinitions();
        return definitions;
    }
}
```

The `Definition` class is annotated by XML annotation and the response in XML contains many definitions like:

```xml
<defition body>
<defition body>
....
```

But I want something like this, I need an ID for each definition in XML, just like:

```xml
<DefinitionList>
    <definition id=1>
        <definition body>
    </definition>
    <definition id=2>
        <definition body>
    </definition>
    ............
</DefinitionsList>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you.

Comment: It works, thanks very much for detail explanations.

Comment: Hi Cassio, I meet a new problem, can you answer this quesion? thanks very much:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860128/how-to-avoid-jaxb-extracting-elements-namespace-and-put-it-at-the-place-of-root

Comment: Sure! Just let me have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a wrapper

Create a `DefinitionWrapper` class annotated like the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "DefinitionList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DefinitionWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "definition")
    private List<Definition> definitions;

    public List<Definition> getDefinitions() {
        return definitions;
    }

    public void setDefinitions(List<Definition> definitions) {
        this.definitions = definitions;
    }
}
```

Ensure the `Definition` class is annotated like the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Definition implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer id;

    // Other fields

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And change your endpoint method to return the `DefinitionWrapper`:

```java
@Path("discoverytopology")
public class DiscoveryTopology {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public DefinitionWrapper getDefinitionList() {
        List<Definition> definitions = db.getDefinitions();
        DefinitionWrapper definitionWrapper = new DefinitionWrapper;
        definitionWrapper.setDefinitions(definitions);
        return definitionWrapper;
   }
}
```

When marshaled to XML, the result will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DefinitionList>
    <definition id="1"/>
    <definition id="2"/>
    <definition id="3"/>
</DefinitionList>
```

---

### Adding an element

Probably you will need other fields than the `id` in your `Definition` class. Consider, for example, you need a `description` field and it should be marshaled as a XML element.

To achieve it, annotated your field with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html), like the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Definition implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer id;

    @XmlElement
    private String description;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

When marshaled to XML, the result will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DefinitionList>
    <definition id="1">
        <text>This is a description</text>
    </definition>
    <definition id="2">
        <text>This is a description</text>
    </definition>
    <definition id="3">
        <text>This is a description</text>
    </definition>
</DefinitionList>
```

---

### Adding a value

You can annotate a field with [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html):

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Definition implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And when your object is marshaled to XML, the result will be the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DefinitionList>
    <definition id="1">This is the value</definition>
    <definition id="2">This is the value</definition>
    <definition id="3">This is the value</definition>
</DefinitionList>
```

However, only one field annotated with [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) is allowed per class. And if a class has any fields annotated with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html), it cannot have any fields annotated with [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need an object that will represent your DefinitionList in an class that will be annotated with `@XMLRootElelement`, and it must contain a list of `Definition`

JAX-B cannot create a `<DefinitionList>` element, unless it knows it exists.

Then you need to annotate `Definition` class properly so that your `<definition>` elements looks like what you want, attributes vs properties etc.

I am not sure if your `<definition body>` withtin `<definition id="1">` is just a filler that means the "body of defintion" but if not, it might get tricky to have 2 elements with different definitions within the same schema. Not sure it is proper XML.